# Plot indicator on chart with different candle setup but same timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I have 2 charts showing Nasdaq 100 E-mini Futures at 1 min intervals, one uses regular OHLC candles and the other uses Heikin Ashi.

I have written a very simple indicator that plots either `shape.triangleup` or `shape.triangledown` on certain candles on the Heikin Ashi chart using its OHLC data and would like to show these on the regular candle chart that is using the same timeframe to use in a seperate indicator/strategy, is this possible?.

Seems like it should be quite simple to do but I cannot find anything online showing me a way to do this, hopefully I am just using the wrong search terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ticker.heikinashi` will create a ticker for the Heikin Ashi bar values. You can then use the `request.security()` function with this ticker id.

```
//@version=5
indicator("ticker.heikinashi", overlay=true) 
heikinashi_close = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)

heikinashi_aapl_60_close = request.security(ticker.heikinashi("AAPL"), "60", close)
plot(heikinashi_close)
plot(heikinashi_aapl_60_close)
```